# What does "Enable update query support" do in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0, sharepoint

In SharePoint 3.0/2007 under *Central Admin* -> *Operations* -> *Data Retrieval Service* there is an option titled *Update Support* which has a single option *Enable update query support*.

The flavor text for the option states, unhelpfully:
*Support for update queries can be controlled with this setting.*
*This setting applies to the following data retrieval services:*

*OLEDB*

This is NOT checked by default.

My question is what does this actually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is enabled you can update the list contents from external program (like excel 2007).

To check this, export your list to Excel, you will get connected to SharePoint list.